# Which third-party apps don't work after a Snow Leopard upgrade?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

What non-Apple apps have you found to be incompatible with Snow Leopard, i.e. stop working, after upgrading to Snow Leopard?

Please include the app name and version number in your answer.

Comment: This is wiki material.  And I believe there is an official list somewhere, just need to find it.

Comment: I don't believe Apple have published an official list, but the one at http://snowleopard.wikidot.com/start (also mentioned by nagul) seems to be the go-to place to check.

Comment: Yep, that was exactly what I was thinking of. Not official, but comprehensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly what you asked, but what you want is here: [Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard Compatibility List](http://snowleopard.wikidot.com/start) . Got this from an [article](http://lifehacker.com/5345306/check-if-your-must+have-applications-are-snow-leopard+compatible) Lifehacker ran a few days back.

**Update:** Here is Apple's official list: [Mac OS X v10.6: About incompatible software](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3258)

Answer (score 0):

- MenuMeters v1.3
- iStatMenus v1.3 Cisco
- Cisco ASDM v61551

Developers for MenuMeters and iStatMenus say that 10.6 compatible versions will be out shortly.